# Regex behavior regarding odd/even number of characters

Tags: javascript, regex

I'm trying to create a regex in JS that will match a text at the end of the string composed by an "@" symbol followed by some characters (anything that's not a whitespace character or another "@").

Here are some examples of some expected behaviors I'm looking for:

| String | Match | Group 1 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| test | *No match* | - |
| @test | @test | test |
| @test aux | *No match* | - |
| @test @aux | @aux | aux |
| @test @@aux | *No match* | - |
| @test @@@aux | @aux | aux |
| @test @@@@aux | *No match* | - |
| @test @@@@@aux | @aux | aux |

The current regex I have - `/(?<!@(?:@@)*)@([^\s@]*)$/` - doesn't work in the last use cases, when more than 3 "@" characters are used. It's supposed to find a match only if an odd number of "@" characters are used.
I would appreciate if someone could help me out with this, thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could change it to assert what is to the left is pairs of `@@` not preceded by a @ itself.

Then match @ and capture 0+ chars other than @ or a whitespace char at the end of the string in group 1.

```
(?<=(?<!@)(?:@@)*)@([^\s@]*)$
```

- `(?<=` Positive lookbehind to asser what is directly to the left is

  - `(?<!@)` Assert not @ directly to the left
  - `(?:@@)*` Match optional pairs of `@@`
- `)` Close lookbehind
- `@` Match a single @
- `([^\s@]*)` Capture 0+ times any char except a whitespace char or @ in **group 1** (if you don't want to match an empty string, you can change `*` to `+`)
- `$` End of string

[regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/kgQI9Z/1)

```js
const pattern = /(?<=(?<!@)(?:@@)*)@([^\s@]*)$/;
[
  "test",
  "@test",
  "@test aux",
  "@test @aux",
  "@test @@aux",
  "@test @@@aux",
  "@test @@@@aux",
  "@test @@@@@aux"
].forEach(s => {
  const m = s.match(pattern);
  if (m) {
    console.log(`${s} --> match: ${m[0]} | group: ${m[1]}`);
  } else {
    console.log(`${s} --> No match`);
  }
});
```

Comment: Thanks, that regex is exactly what I needed and I appreciate the edit you've done with the JS code as well.

Comment: Do you have any way of achieving the same results without using lookbehinds? I need to support Safari

Answer (score 2):

You may use `match` here:

```js
input = ["@test @aux", "@test @@aux", "@test @@@aux"];
for (var i = 0; i < input.length; ++i) {
    result = input[i].match(/(?:^|\s)(?:@@)*@(\w+)$/);
    if (result) {
        output = "Match: " + result[0].trim() + ", " +
                 "Group 1: " + result[1];
        console.log(output);
    }
}
```

Here is an explanation of the regex pattern:

```regex
(?:^|\s)  what precedes is either whitespace
          or the start of the string (for single word inputs)
(?:@@)*   match any EVEN number of @
@         match a single @ (therefore odd total number of @)
(\w+)     match and capture word portion of @symbol
$         end of the input
```

Comment: I marked the other answer as the accepted one because that regex was exactly what I needed, but I appreciate your detailed answer as well, it is well structured and the JS part also helped me a lot. Thanks